# Update Django template without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have Django code like below and I am getting connected device details dynamically and I am updating in template. I am getting what I want but I want to refresh every time to know whether any new devices are connected or not.

Here is my view code:

```
class UserDashBoard(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDashBoard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_devices'] = get_device_mac_details(cmd='iw dev wlan0 station dump |grep Station |wc -l')
        return context
```

Here is what my template looks like:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-left">MAC Id</th>
    </tr>
    {% for device in total_devices %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">{{ device }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I get details without refreshing page?

Comment: using `ajax`...

Comment: I tried but i am not getting it

Comment: Please understand that this question seems to be too broad. I can guide you. So first of all understand that you need to send a request to database for each time you need new data. Then decide how many seconds you need. Then decide how to update ONLY the part where the devices are listed. Work on this one by one. Maybe post separate questions for each part. You will find more answers if you do that. I can solve your problem, but I feel like you haven't done your homework.

Comment: There is no db interaction here, I am getting those device details by using script that should be dynamdynamic